# Passing html value as function parameter on golang fiber

Tags: javascript, html, go, go-fiber

i was searching for passing html value as a parameter on golang fiber but still got no answers.

javascript:

```
function monthPicker() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("datePicker").value);
    var date = document.getElementById("datePicker").value;
    var d = {{.data.GetWeek date}};
    console.log(d)
}
```

viewdata function:

```
func (v ViewData) GetWeek(date string) int {
    n, err := time.Parse("2006-01", date)
    if nil != err {
        return 0
    }

    _, week := n.ISOWeek()

    return week
}
```

Comment: From the description of the problem it isn't immediately clear what you are trying to achieve. I am going to try to guess. Are you looking to create a handler in go/fiber and then call this handler from Javascript code?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to call a method from a Go template. This would work if you passed the correct `.data` object to the template execution. Show how you are evaluating that template.

Comment: this way how i define my viewdata
```
type ViewData struct {
 Chart        *AdministrationChartData
 MonthlyGraph *AdministrationChartData
}

func (v ViewData) GetWeek(date string) int {
 n, err := time.Parse("2006-01", date)
 if nil != err {
  return 0
 }

 _, week := n.ISOWeek()

 return week
}
```